# Custom View suspension state

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

A have a view controller on which I have a custom view.

The custom view draws some shape layers.

I noticed when my app is in the background if I reopen it after so many minutes the custom view is redrawn but the old shape layers are still there so I end up with two lots of shapes.

I also noticed that delegates are not being fired. It would seem that all references to objects that were created in the custom view have been lost.

I presume this is something to do with saving state , but I am not using any state saving features.

How can I make sure my app reopens completely fresh after being restored from suspended state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent your app state from being saved when entering background state...

Open the .plist and add the following key:

```
Application does not run in background  -  Boolean  - YES
```

This has the effect of forcing your app to reload on launch.